# Many instances of a terminal symbol in a BNF grammar

Tags: grammar, bnf

given a grammar like

```
<term>::= x[i]+exp(x[i]) | x[i]
<i>::= 1|2|3
```

Does a way exist to force the use of the same "i" in one solution of non terminal symbol ? So, I want to avoid solutions like x[1]+exp(2) or x[3]+exp(1)
Does a way exist to avoid that the same "i" is used in one solution of non terminal symbol ?So, I want to avoid solutions like x[1]+exp(1)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible with a context-free grammar.

This is essentially what "context-free" means. Every non-terminal in a production can be expanded independently without regard to the context in which it appears.

Of course, if `i` really only has three possible values, you can enumerate the finite number of legal productions, according to any definition of "legal" which you find convenient. But that gets really messy when the number of possibilities increases.

The most convenient solution is generally to accept the base syntax and check for concordance (or difference) in the associated semantic rule. That also allows for better error messages.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You response was very clear. When you wrote "check for concordance or difference" did you mean to verify after the production if the rule satisfies my constraints, isn't it?

Comment: @antonio: precisely.